# converting filenames to lower case

Tags: c#

was hoping for some advice as to how to convert existing file names in a folder...all to lower case.

I felt that a good start would be to save the file names in a list and convert them all to lower.

How can I replace the existing file names in the folder to the lower case ones?

```
List<string> codes = new List<string>();
string[]productCodes = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Ariang\Desktop\screenshotslowercase\screenshots");         

codes = productCodes.ToList();
codes = codes.ConvertAll(t => t.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp\testrename"))
{
    File.Move(file, file.ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

A few notes, first of all I have tested this and it works, somebody else mentioned using a temporary variable, but I haven't needed to do this.

Also, I have run this multiple times on the same directory, and I don't get an IOException the second or third time around, so I don't think any additional checking is necessary.

However, I am on Windows 8 and targeting .Net 4.5, things may be different on earlier versions of Windows or .Net.

Comment: I'd use `ToLowerInvariant()`. You never know what might happen if you don't.

Comment: @StevenLiekens Are you talking about turkish i?

Comment: Two notes, both from the [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) description: "Note that if you attempt to replace a file by moving a file of the same name into that directory, you get an IOException." and "You cannot use the Move method to overwrite an existing file." You might want to check this, in case your file name already is all-lowercase.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I'm not familiar with differences in `ToLower()` between different cultures. Anyway I think it's better to make a filesystem function behave consistently regardless of your language settings.

Answer (score 1):

no need for list and all that. Simple read the file name from directory and use

```
System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "oldfilename".ToLower());



string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
foreach(string file in files)
{        
    System.IO.File.Move(file, file.ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows system doesn't see difference betweeen lower and upper letters in file names. Thats why you can't convert like "MyFile" -> "myfile". Use two steps instead:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp\testrename"))
{
   var tempName = "." + file.ToLowerInvariant();
   File.Move(file, tempName);
   File.Move(tempName, file.ToLowerInvariant());
}
```